# VoIP conference with multiple incoming SIP calls

Tags: linux, voip

I want to set up a **VoIP system** to allow people to remotely listen to given speeches in place.

We have a VoIP line which can receives up to 8 **incoming calls**. The soft will accept them with or without confirmation (we can work with a white list for example).

I tried [Ekiga](http://www.ekiga.org/), but it seems not to manage multiple incoming calls. [Linephone](http://www.linphone.org/) seems to be good, I succeeded to set a conference call between three SIP lines but I had to do it manually. [Twinkle](http://twinklephone.com/) and [Yate](http://yate.ro/) didn't work well (Linux Mint 17.x). I also saw [pjsua](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsua.htm), a command line soft, but not yet tested. So I need now some hints from the Internet.

PS:  Allowing listeners to put their word in, for example by typing "*", would be a plus.

Comment: are you in particular looking for a SIP client, or is any other VoIP system welcome?

Comment: We have a SIP line form an ISP. The best will be an "out-of-the-box" client. The least solution will be an API. I'm a developper, so I could also write the client myselft, but I rather not (free time issues, also I'm a beginner in Python wich seems to be the best solution). What kind of system are you thinking of ?

Answer (score 2):

well there are two ways that comes in my mind:

the first is sicking with SIP (which is fine)... so i would try [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/):

- it is free (as in beer and speech)
- capable of conference calls
- isn't available via the default repositories but they provide [pre-compiled packages](https://jitsi.org/Main/Download) and maintain [their own repository](https://jitsi.org/Main/DebianRepository)

<sup>i have to add, that i don't like the GUI of Jitsi but the functions are pretty good!</sup>

maybe also [Ring](https://ring.cx/) is worth a try since it is the successor of SFLphone and it uses [PJSIP](https://ring.cx/en/about/technical#PJSIP), therefore it is SIP-capable, just don't create a Ring-account...

---

the second way... for a "closed environment/user-base" [Mumble](https://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Main_Page) is interesting:

- it is also free (as in beer and speech)
- Automatic Level Equalization
- Noise Suppression
- Priority Speakers
- clients for several platforms (also Android and iOS)
- it is often used by gamers with special features like [in-app-Overlay](https://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Overlay) or [Positional-Audio](https://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Positional-Audio), but they can be deactivated.

maybe create a separate room with password-protection on a public server or you can also host your own server ([Murmur](https://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Running_Murmur)) to have full control.

Comment: I think I tried Jistsi (cannot retry now, I'm not there). Maybe I'm wrong, but although it supports conference  calls, do I have to create them _manually_ by filling SIP numbers/ids (i.e. it cannot manage multiple incoming calls) ? Also I will give a feedback if I'll try these softs you listed. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here's my feeling. I think we have the tools/bricks, but it's hard to find an out-of-the-box free software (or even free as free bier) solution.

The best way, in my humble opinion, is a to build a python-based apps with [PJSUA module](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP_Tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Twilio. 
They are a little bit expensive, but they are the liders on this kind of applications.